# Вызов метода из promise

Tags: javascript, promise

Пытаюсь построить нужную мне цепочку вызовов

```
IsInNameGroup(){

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

        var currentUserId = Xrm.Utility.getGlobalContext().userSettings.userId;

        var fetch = `my fetch`;

        fetchXML = "?fetchXml=" + encodeURIComponent(fetch);

        
        Xrm.WebApi.retrieveMultipleRecords("role", fetchXML).then(
            function success(result) {
            var res = false;
            if(result.entities.length === 1){
                res = true; 
            }
            resolve(res);
        },
        function (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
        }
        );

    });
},

OnClick: function(primaryControl){

    let p = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        let result = this.IsInNameGroup(); 
        result.then(res =>{
            debugger;
            resolve(res);
        });
    });
    p.then(res => {alert(res);});
    alert("халлоу");
    
},
```

В конечном итоге, должно получится так, что метод `OnClick` сперва выводит результат работы метода `IsInNameGroup (true/false)`, и только после этого алерт `alert("халлоу");`
На данный момент мой код сперва выводит `"халлоу"`, и потом выкидывает в консоль `"TypeError: this.IsInNameGroup is not a function"`. В целом да, `IsInNameGroup` действительно не функция, а метод. Но как исправить код и получить нужный мне порядок выполнения? `OnClick` делать `async` нельзя, т.к. это `handler` (просто напросто не работает будучи `async`).

Comment: Выложите пример, который можно запустить. И посмотрите в сторону https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Answer (score 1):

Не стал тянуть весь ваш код. Но в целом должно быть понятно.

```js
const fetchPromise = () => new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve(true);
  }, 1000);
});

const onClick = async () => {
  const fetchResult = await fetchPromise();
  console.log(fetchResult);
  console.log('Хеллоу');
};

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener("click", onClick);
```

```html
<button id="button">Супер кнопка</button>
```